# Finding the best subgraph

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, subgraph

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given a connected graph G = (V, E) and a vertex t ∈ V, I need to find a subgraph G'= (V', E ') where t ∈ V'. G' should maximize some objective function and minimize the count of vertexes it contains.

```
Max f(G')
Min |V'|
```

In this multi-objective optimization problem, maximize f (G') is more important than minimize the number of vertexes.

Let's check a practical situation with a similar problem:

Suppose that we have to design an ad hoc wireless network in a building where the client devices have a fixed location and there's just one AP connected to the wired network. Initially we put an AP on every room and calculate, using a propagation model, the APs that can be connected and the client devices for which they provide coverage. In this initial distribution probably several APs will provide coverage to the same client device, so we need to optimize it.

[image: Red dot represents the AP connected to the wired network and black dots denote the rest of the APs. Solid lines between APs show us how they are connected]

Fig 1. Red dot represents the AP connected to the wired network and black dots denote the rest of the APs. Solid lines between APs show us how they are connected.

The graph that form the APs’s connections in the fig 1 represents the connected graph G of our problem and the AP connected to the wired network is the node t. Optimize the graph that represent this initial network design implies to find a subgraph that contains the AP connected to the wired network and maximize the percent of covered client devices (Max f(G') )  minimizing the count of APs (Min |V’|). Like in the problem, maximize the percent of covered client devices is the main target.

[image: A possible solution]

Fig 2. A possible solution.

Using brute-force algorithm, it seems like a NP-Completeness problem; find the optimal solution require examining all potential subgraphs (all containing the node t) and proofing a possible solution too. What do you think about?

Comment: If we specialize the problem a little bit would it be ok to find all vertex shortest paths (using f' as metric) in O(n^3) and the find vertex with minimum (maximum) sum of distances from other vertices? And use this vertex as answer?

Comment: Thanks Eugen, an interesting idea to find shortest path between all vertexes using f funtion as metric. Notice I'm looking for a subgraph, not a node; I don't understand your last question.

Comment: It seems I am a little misunderstood your question. Ok, maybe I would think about the problem one of the next days.

Comment: They way it is stated now, this problem sounds hard. What does `f` look like? You will likely have to exploit various properties of `f`to guide your search through the solution space. Another way to soften the problem: Would a x-approximation suffice? The more specific information you can provide, the easier it becomes to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NP-complete.  Let *f(G') =* 1 if *G'* is a complete graph on *k* vertices and 0 otherwise.  Now this problem is simply finding if *G* has a clique of size *k*.